# NVIDIA OpenCL Device Version

Tags: gpu, opencl, nvidia

NVIDIA has recently announced OpenCL 3.0 support for their graphics cards. I have NVIDIA Geforce MX150 card and I have updated my CUDA toolkit to version 11.3 with 465.19.01 driver. I have installed clinfo tool that displays all information regarding OpenCL platforms and devices. When I run it, it dislpays:

- Device Version = OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
- Driver Version = 465.19.01
- Device OpenCL C Version = OpenCL C 1.2

I am a bit confused here. What is the difference between Device version & Device OpenCL C version? Will I be able to run OpenCL 3.0 code on my card or it just still support OpenCL 1.2 specs?

Comment: The OpenCL 3.0 support announcement is [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-is-now-opencl-3-0-conformant/) and the detailed list of new features supported is in [the release notes](https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/465.89/465.89-win10-win8-win7-release-notes.pdf).  You'll be able to run OpenCL 3.0 code as described in those links on a Maxwell (or newer) GPU with driver 465.xx or newer.  MX150 is a Pascal architecture GPU so it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`clGetDeviceInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) specification:

`CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION` is the highest OpenCL C language version that the compiler supports for this device.

`CL_DEVICE_VERSION` is the OpenCL version supported by the device.

So even though your MX150 supports OpenCL 3.0, you can only compile OpenCL 1.2 code. Note that OpenCL 3.0 basically is identical to OpenCL 1.2 but with better support for optional OpenCL 2.x features. With the lates driver Nvidia has added a few new OpenCL 2.x features, but still has no full 2.x support.

Comment: You can compile OpenCL 2.0 and 3.0 code using key "-cl-std=CL2.0" or I suppose new CL3.0.